# find and delete lines matching a condition

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I have three different files which contain columns of numbers in them. These files are very large (having 50,000,000+ lines in them)

as an example, the data format looks like

```
1.2 22.333 10002.3432 223.2111
50.2166 2.873 15402.3432 322.1
.
.
.
```

For each of files (file1, file2 and file3) I need to do the followng:

**FILE1**
  Find the lines containing any number x <=1000 and delete the lines from file1

**FILE2**
Find the lines containing any number x >=1800 and delete the lines from file2

**FILE3**
Find the lines containing any number 1000<= x <=1800 and delete the lines from file3.

My knowledge of REGEX is not sufficient to figure out how to achieve this quickly. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Comparing numbers is generally not the task regex is used for.

Comment: sed and regexes probably won't help because they don't understand numbers. Awk might do it, but I would recommend perl for this task.

Comment: +1 to all for beating me so quickly... Man it's hard to answer new questions here.  lol

Comment: Did you really mean for x == 1800 or x == 1000 to be deleted from all files? Or did you say `<=` when you really meant `<`? E.g. if x = 1000, then it is both <= 1000 AND >= 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where the input file "sample" is:

```
500 500 500
1000 1000 1000
2000 2000 2000
3000 3000 3000
```

Strip `x <= 1000`:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i <= 1000) next } print }' < sample
2000 2000 2000
3000 3000 3000
```

Strip `x >= 1800`:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i >= 1800) next } print }' < sample
500 500 500
1000 1000 1000
```

Strip `1000 <= x <= 1800`:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if (1000 <= $i && $i <= 1800) next } print }' < sample
500 500 500
2000 2000 2000
3000 3000 3000
```

Comment: aha... we seemed to have come up with identical solutions. +1 for beating me by 20 secs ;)

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned in the comments, regex is not ideal in this case.

Here's one way of doing it using `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i<=1000) next}; if (NF) print}' file1 > new1
```

That parses `file` and suppresses any lines any contains numbers `<= 1000` (and empty lines). The output is then piped to a new file.

For `file2` and `file3`, simply change the conditions in the relevant if statement to match your requirements.

---

Here's a quick explanation:

```
         This is repeated for each line in the input file
                                |
      -------------------------------------------------------
     /                                                       \
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i<=1000) next}; if (NF) print}'
      ------------------   ------------------   -------------
             |                     |                  |
     for each field/column         |                  |
                                   |                  |
                      If condition is met, skip       |
                             this line                |
                                                      |
                                          otherwise, if the line is
                                          not empty (number of fields != 0)
                                          print out the whole line.
```

Comment: which part suppresses empty lines? is that second if-statement?

Comment: @regex99 The "`if (NF)`" bit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reasonably short Perl script that outputs your FILE3:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

our $lower = 1000.0;
our $upper = 1800.0;

OUTER: while (<>) {
    $_ >= $lower && $_ < $upper and next OUTER for /(\S+)/g;
    print;
}
```

You can adjust for FILE1 and FILE2.

(For better or for worse, my script is thick with basic Perl idiom, which despite the script's brevity makes it almost unreadable if you don't know Perl.  Still, that's how it's done in Perl, a scripting language you would enjoy learning, one suspects.)

Comment: not bad, yeah. good and simple script with all perl features. like your style.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following script should work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while(<>) {
    my $line = $_;
    foreach my $col (split ' ', $line){     #for each column
        unless ($col <= 1000) {
            print $line;
        }
        #add other statements for other files
    }
}
```

**Edit** - Made code more efficient Thanks TLP

Comment: Not as short as others, but is readable and get the jobs done.

Comment: You should use `for my $col (split ' ', $line)` instead of using an index. You should use `split ' '` or else double spaces will insert empty strings in your list. And storing 50,000,000+ elements in your array and printing them will reak havok with your performance -- you should just print the lines right away.

Comment: Good call, guess I missed a couple things.